# Django and limiting RAM usage: Recommended syntax, conventions, and strategies?

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, ram

my django project is hosted using apache2 server has been consuming a ton of memory lately and i'm not sure if unusual or if something is being systematically done incorrectly in the project.

For the record, debug is set to False, memory leaks are being monitored and do not exist, the django queryset database has been cleared, and all static references are hosted on a seperate static application.

Here is the specific memory consumption:

```
2120 /home/path/apache2/bin/httpd.worker -f /home/path/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
46408 /home/path/apache2/bin/httpd.worker -f /home/path/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
47124  /home/path/apache2/bin/httpd.worker -f /home/path/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
4800 /home/path/apache2/bin/httpd.worker -f /home/path/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

**Misunderstandings and questions:**

What actually ends up costing memory and RAM? a queryset call? Defining a view? Everything? I know this is a really elementary question but I only have an abstract understanding of how servers and web applications interact.

For an industrial project, is:

```
Model.objects.all()
```

Really really bad? Or should everything be filtered as much as possible?

Is a rss of 46408 and 47124 considered overwhelmingly large for a django project? Or should I not even be concerned about optimizing the RAM usage further?

Every view in my project is being responded to with at least three SomeModel.objects.all() calls. Does this severely hurt performance, or does it not matter?

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing any performance problems?

Comment: None, the website is running fine. The problems however are related to RAM restrictions on my web hosting plan :/

Comment: By the way, is your hosting OpenVZ or Virtuozzo-based? If so then VIRT memory is restricted, not RSS, and apache (just like all thread-based servers) is known to consume a *lot* of VIRT memory.

Answer (score 1):

Not every `Model.objects.all()` results in evaluating all items. QuerySets in Django are lazy evaluated. If you are not doing stupid things like `len(Model.objects.all())` which evaluates it right now, you probably do not end with those evaluations. At least not always - e.g. all paginators limits querysets and so on.

One of the most RAM consuming things in Django I experienced was when displaying select box in admin consisting of hundreds of thousands possible related objects... (ant that is why `raw_id_fields` are available).

Comment: So if I remove the admin interface from the URL's will I be saving memory?